# Like enum but for objects

Tags: c#

I have a custom class "Error" and some pre-created errors (let's call them A, B and C). Now I'd love to group these pre-created ones under one group (for example, "StockErrors") and use them kind of like an enum:

```
private void SomeFunction(Error NewError)
{
    if (NewError == StockErrors.A) DoSomething(); // this is what I need.
}
```

Any ideas how I could accomplish this? It's probably something extremely simple...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, you guys are amazing! Worked flawlessly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a `static` class called `StockErrors` with `public static readonly` fields of type `Error` that are initialized to the appropriate values.  (You can also use properties)

Depending on your `Error` class, you may also need to override `==`, `!=`, `Equals`, and `GetHashCode` to use value semantics.

Comment: Alternatively to overriding the equality comparisons one could make all constructors private and expose the instances only via the static properties as singletons and then rely on object identity.

Comment: @Daniel: He said _some_ values.

Comment: Singleton is not the absolutely correct term - I mean one instance per specific error.

Comment: @Daniel: As opposed to other values.  He does want a public constructor.  BTW, I call that pattern a "Multiton"

Comment: Now I got the point - he probably needs to create other instances.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public static class StockErrors
{
    public static readonly Error A = new Error("A");
    public static readonly Error B = new Error("B");
    public static readonly Error C = new Error("B");
}
```

That's the dead simplest declaration, though it exposes fields, which is generally considered bad form. To make it a little more acceptable, you could declare the fields as `private`, then expose them in `public static` properties.

Also, if your `Error` class can't be constructed solely based on constant values, then you would need to initialize the variables in the static constructor. Here's an example where the values are exposed by properties and initialized in the static constructor:

```
public static class StockErrors
{
    private static readonly Error a;
    private static readonly Error b;
    private static readonly Error c;

    public static Error A { get { return a; } }
    public static Error B { get { return b; } }
    public static Error C { get { return c; } }

    static StockErrors()
    {
        a = new Error(...);
        b = new Error(...);
        c = new Error(...);
    }
}
```